# What is the AAD role required to GET Microsoft defender ATP data from API into PowerBI?

Tags: api, security, azure-active-directory, powerbi, roles

I would like to know what is the AAD role required to GET Microsoft defender ATP data from API into Power BI?

Thanks

Comment: Full access rights are granted to users with Security Administrator or Global Administrator roles in Azure AD. Read only access is granted to users with a Security Reader role in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

You should be a member of Security reader role in azure ad to get the data from API.